# Django filter relationship in models.py

Tags: python, django

Assuming the following scenario at two seperated apps where I want to count the number of post elements of a specific category at my template:

Categories/models.py

```
from Posts.models import Post
...
class Category(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name="Title")
    ...

    @property
    def posts(self):
        return Post.objects.filter(category_id=self.id).count()
```

Posts/models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(verbose_name="Title")
    content = models.TextField(verbose_name="Content")
    tag = models.CharField(verbose_name="Meta", max_length=70, blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

template.html:

```
<h5>Number of Post elements: {{ category.posts }}</h5>
```

sadly this always results in the following error:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'Post' from partially initialized
>   module 'Posts.models' (most likely due to a circular import)

Comment: you have `from Posts.models import Post` in your `Categories` model?

Comment: Yes i do. Thanks for your hint, just updated my question accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely because you import `Posts.models` in your `Categories.models` and *vice-versa*. You can import this in the property itself:

```
# no from Posts.models import Post

# …

class Category(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name="Title")
    # …

    @property
    def posts(self):
        from Posts.models import Post
        return Post.objects.filter(category_id=self.id).count()
```

But you do not need to import this model. Django automatically creates a relation in reverse. If you do not specify the `related_name`, that is `modelname_set`, so you can acccess this with:

```
# no from Posts.models import Post

# …

class Category(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name="Title")
    # …

    @property
    def posts(self):
        return self.post_set.count()
```

> **Note**: Python modules are normally written in *snake_case*, not *PerlCase*, so it
>   should be `category`, not <s>`Category`</s>.

Comment: Thanks for that :) i prefer the first solution has it's still possible to query for other fields, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should try using the related name in your property:

```py
class Category(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name="Title")
    ...

    @property
    def posts(self):
        return self.post_set.count()
```

Also, for the record, it seems odd to have `Category` and `Post` in separate apps. Likely they should be in a single `blog` app. Circular imports generally imply you have two apps that are too tightly-coupled. In this case, it should probably be just one app.

Answer (score 0):

The hint is in the error as you do indeed have a circular import.

Posts.models.py will have `from Categories.models import Category` at the top as you are using it as a foreign key and as you are now using Post within the posts method of Category it will have `from Posys.models import Post`

You need to fix this which you can do in one of three ways depending if you have other models or methods using the Post class from within the Categories model.

If you do then you can  use one of these two

1. Change the foreignKey to pass in a string rather than the Category object so

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(verbose_name="Title")
    content = models.TextField(verbose_name="Content")
    tag = models.CharField(verbose_name="Meta", max_length=70, blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey("Category", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

2. Move the import from the top of Categories/models.py inside the posts method so that it imports locally

```py
class Category(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name="Title")

    @property
    def posts(self):
        from Posts.models import Post
        return Post.objects.filter(category_id=self.id).count()
```

If you don't, and we can't tell from what you have posted, then you can just use the ```post_set`` related name within the Category class and avoid the import at all. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#be-careful-with-related-name-and-related-query-name

```
    @property
    def posts(self):
        return self.post_set.count()
```

This will also fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

No need for that property, you can access the related objects by following the foreign key backwards. See the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward)

```
<h5>Number of Post elements: {{ category.post_set.count }}</h5>
```

Or you can add a property but directly:

```
@property
def post_count(self):
    return self.post_set.count()
```

And then:

```
<h5>Number of Post elements: {{ category.post_count }}</h5>
```